# how to use spring admin in my existing spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wanted to monitor my web application deployed in the production environment, monitoring tool notify me when the server down or any abnormal cases for that I decided to use spring admin, plz help to find the best resource for set upping spring admin with the spring boot project (correctly I'm using java melody for monitoring purpose, but I does not allow email notification)

Comment: There are tools. Monitor programs like Dynatrace, WatchDog and so on. It is just watch your application and not will do operations. Or you will write rebooter micro program in python or bash. Or you can use Docker or Kubernetes.
Essentially not spring specific what you want. This is an application operation topic.

Comment: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-admin/ this will help me...